# IE throws JavaScript Error (Works on other browser)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I'm having a real problem with JavaScript scope in IE 7.

I have declared function at top of page like following

```
function close_fancy()
{
  $.fancybox.close();

}
```

called function on

```
<input type="reset" name="reset" id="button2" value="Close'" onclick="close_fancy();"/>
```

its working on all major browsers except IE-7 it throws following error

```
The value of the property 'close_fancy' is null or undefined, not a Function object
```

Please Help Me On This...

Comment: try placing close_fancy() function inside body of html document just before </body> tag

Comment: is your script tag correctly labeled `type="text/javascript"`? This could be a problem in IE7

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

Comment: What makes you think the OP is using frames?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you should be writing it in a jQuery style.

This means not using `onclick=` in the HTML code, but instead writing a `$(elem).click()` function, like so:

```
$('#button2').click(function() {
    $.fancybox.close();
}
```

You then don't need a separate `close_fancy` function at all.

As per normal with jQuery, this code should be placed in a javascript block at the foot of your page, or inside a `$(document).ready()` function.